# Method to check whether a date is a Holiday

Tags: apex

Tried a lot to write a method to check whether a day is a holiday. I want an Apex class/method to check whether a day is holiday according to a particular business hour that is defined in the system. It should dynamically consider all the holidays that are entered in the business hour. Please suggest a way to check the same.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific country's holidays or something more generic?

Comment: Do you mean just a weekend, not a weekday?

Comment: Sorry missed few part in the description. I want a apex class/method to check whether a day is holiday according to a particular Business hour that is defined in the system. It should dynamically consider all the holiday that is entered in the Business hour.

Answer (score 7):

I have an apex class that does something like this.

It uses the businesshour.add method.  Basically, if you add one millisecond to system.now() and it's still the same date, then you know that you are within the business hours (otherwise, that second would kick you into the next day when you re-open).  If you don't specify one, or it's not there, it'll default to your org default business hours.

So to use this to find holidays, set up a business hours (org settings) where you're 24/7 but with some holidays.  Mine is testing that we ARE open, so based on your question you might want to switch the true/false condition to return true when it IS a holiday.

```
public static boolean isItBusinessHours (string bhname){
    Businesshours bh = new Businesshours();
    try{
         bh = [select id from businesshours where name =: bhname];
    } catch (exception e){
        bh = [select id from businesshours where isdefault= true];
    } 
    return (businesshours.add(bh.id, system.now(), 1).day()==system.now().day());
}
```

Comment: Well I did something like this only. Will be posting the solution soon.

Answer (score 3):

I basically did the same thing but instead of check for same date I added 5 seconds to now and checked to see if it was less than the next business hour second.

```
datetime now = system.now(); 

BusinessHours bh = [select id from BusinessHours where Name = 'your business hour name'];
Datetime check = BusinessHours.add(bh.id, now, 1000L); 

if(now.addSeconds(5) < check) {
    system.debug('outside bus hours');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Public static boolean isHoliday(Date checkDate) {
    BusinessHours bt = [SELECT Id,MondayStartTime FROM BusinessHours 
        WHERE isDefault = true];
    Datetime checkDatetime = Datetime.newInstance(checkDate.year(), checkDate.month(), checkDate.day(), 
        bt.MondayStartTime.hour(), bt.MondayStartTime.minute(), bt.MondayStartTime.second());
    return !BusinessHours.isWithin(bt.Id,checkDateTime);
}
```

the method `isWithin(businessHoursId, targetDate)` return true if the inserted datetime is a working day, based on the BusinessHours passed [(Apex Developer Guide)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_businesshours.htm)

In this case, I'm assuming that the work starts at the same hour for each working day of the week.

Comment: This answer is useful, but doesn't really address *holidays*, which was the original intent of the question.

Comment: It depends. If he's talking about only holidays (excluding weekends), you're right. Otherwise, in this way you can understand if the inserted day is a non-working day (weekend or holiday) using the negation. I'm sorry for my english, i know it's not perfect :D