# How to run a scheduled flow on business days?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, case

I am trying to run a flow that changes a case owner if no one has taken the case from a queue after 24 hours. However, I only want this run on business days and non-holidays. I am trying a scheduled-flow and it does not allow for this option.

Case escalation is not applicable since the owner should be based ona field.

Answer (score 4):

An approach to this problem is as follows

- Run the scheduled flow every day
- Use a decision block as the first element to decide if the rundate is a business day. If yes, continue to the other flow elements. If not, do nothing

How you decide whether it is a business day can be as simple as a formula that looks to see if the run date is a weekend day. If you need to include holidays, you can use an [invocable apex to decide if it is a holiday](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4161/method-to-check-whether-a-date-is-a-holiday)

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same boat here but for Business Hours. I would like the scheduled path to run only during business hours.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please see the note about "me too!" responses in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), and be aware that this "answer" will most likely be deleted. Please contribute to SFSE in other ways so that you gain reputation - you only need 15 rep to upvote a question and only 50 rep to comment under someone else's question. You can always Follow a question for updates. Or you could ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and in it link to this one for reference.